# Реализация прямого обхода бинарного дерева на с++

Tags: c++, структуры, бинарное-дерево

Здравствуйте, помогите с написанием функции для обхода дерева прямым обходом. И возможно ли строить дерево без рекурсий ?

Есть дерево на структуре.

```
# include <iostream.h>
# include <conio.h>

//Наша структура
struct node
{
    int info; //Информационное поле
    node *l, *r;//Левая и Правая часть дерева
};

node * tree=NULL; //Объявляем переменную, тип которой структура Дерево

/*ФУНКЦИЯ ЗАПИСИ ЭЛЕМЕНТА В БИНАРНОЕ ДЕРЕВО*/
void push(int a,node **t)
{
    if ((*t)==NULL) //Если дерева не существует
    {
        (*t)=new node; //Выделяем память
        (*t)->info=a; //Кладем в выделенное место аргумент a
        (*t)->l=(*t)->r=NULL; //Очищаем память для следующего роста
        return; //Заложили семечко, выходим
    }
       //Дерево есть
        if (a>(*t)->info) push(a,&(*t)->r); //Если аргумент а больше чем текущий элемент, кладем его вправо
        else push(a,&(*t)->l); //Иначе кладем его влево
}

/*ФУНКЦИЯ ОТОБРАЖЕНИЯ ДЕРЕВА НА ЭКРАНЕ*/
void print (node *t,int u) 
{
    if (t==NULL) return; //Если дерево пустое, то отображать нечего, выходим
    else //Иначе
    {
    print(t->l,++u);//С помощью рекурсивного посещаем левое поддерево
    for (int i=0;i<u;++i) cout<<"|";
    cout<<t->info<<endl; //И показываем элемент
    u--;
    }
    print(t->r,++u); //С помощью рекурсии посещаем правое поддерево
}

void main ()
{   
    int n; //Количество элементов
    int s; //Число, передаваемое в дерево
    cout<<"введите количество элементов  ";
    cin>>n; //Вводим количество элементов

    for (int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
    cout<<"ведите число  ";
    cin>>s; //Считываем элемент за элементом

    push(s,&tree); //И каждый кладем в дерево
    }
    cout<<"ваше дерево\n";
    print(tree,0);
    getch();       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну собственно просто поменять порядок вывода информации:

Обход в прямом порядке:

```
Посетить узел
Обойти левое поддерево
Обойти правое поддерево
```

Симметричный обход

```
Обойти левое поддерево
Посетить узел
Обойти правое поддерево
```

Обход в обратном порядке

```
Обойти левое поддерево
Обойти правое поддерево
Посетить узел
```

Вы написали случай симметричного обхода. Так будет выглядеть прямой порядок:

```
void print(node *t, int u)
{
    if (t == NULL) return;  
    for (int i = 0; i<u; ++i) cout << "|";
    cout << t->info << endl; //И показываем элемент
    u--;
    print(t->l, ++u);//С помощью рекурсивного посещаем левое поддерево
    print(t->r, ++u); //С помощью рекурсии посещаем правое поддерево
}
```

P.S. Не разбирался в ваших 'u', так что если что-то не так, то проверьте

Насчет нерекурсивного обхода можете посмотреть данный [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10372118/1988244)